# C++ partial template specialization of stream operator

Tags: c++, template-specialization, ostream, friend-function

I have a Matrix class with a friend function to use with operator<<. This all works fine but I now want to partially specialize that friend function to work differently if the Matrix class has Matrix as its template parameter (i.e. when the instance of the class has been declared like Matrix< Matrix< char > >). In the class definition first I had

```
template <typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<U>& other);
```

and I tried adding

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<Matrix<char> >& other);
```

but this gave me multiple declaration errors from the compiler.
I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[There's no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).**

You need overloading, not specialization. This should compile, link, and run cleanly (it does for me):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
  public:
    template <typename U> friend std::ostream& 
        operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<U>& other);
    friend std::ostream& 
        operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<Matrix<char> >& other);    
};


template <typename U>
std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<U>& other)
{
    output << "generic\n";
    return output;
}

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<Matrix<char> >& other)
{
    output << "overloaded\n";
    return output;
}

int main ()
{
    Matrix<int> a;
    std::cout << a;

    Matrix<Matrix<char> > b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

If you are getting compiler errors from this, you probably have a buggy compiler.

Comment: If I use your code I get multiple definition error from the compiler (gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819) when I try to use an instance of matrix with the << operator

Comment: Updated the code to be a complete linkable runnable program. Works under g++-4.4.5 and g++-4.6.1. You could get multiple definitions if you put a definition of the second `<<` function in the header file. Don't. It's not a template.

Comment: your last comment here was the key change I needed to make. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the specialization explicitly:

```
template <>
friend std::ostream& operator<< <Matrix<char> >(std::ostream& output,
                                       const Matrix<Matrix<char> >& other);
```

Comment: The specialization would be <Matrix<char> > not <char>

Comment: @CodeButcher But in the original version the parameter is Matrix<U>.

Comment: @selalerer Maybe it is more clear if I say that I want to create an instance of the class like this: Matrix< Matrix< char > >